# gem contains itself error for CLI Data gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

I just built a CLI Data gem and published it to RubyGems. Now if I try to do bundle install, I get the following error

``

```
You have one or more invalid gemspecs that need to be fixed. 
  The gemspec at 
  /home/himachhag-45739/code/popular-deals-from-slickdeals.net-`cli/popular_deals.gemspec` 
  is not valid. Please fix this gemspec. 
  The validation error was 'popular_deals-0.1.0 contains itself 
  (popular_deals-0.1.0.gem), check your files list'
```

Please see below my gmspec file:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'popular_deals/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "popular_deals"
  spec.version       = PopularDeals::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["'Hima Chitalia'"]
  spec.email         = ["'hima_chhag@yahoo.com'"]

  spec.summary       = %q{It displays popular deals of the day from https://slickdeals.net/deals/.}
  #spec.description   = %q{It displays popular deals of the day from https://slickdeals.net/deals/.}
  spec.homepage      = "https://github.com/HimaChitalia/popular_deals"
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject do |f|
     f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
   end
    spec.bindir        = "exe"
   spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
   spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.14"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "pry"

  spec.add_dependency "nokogiri"
  spec.add_dependency "colorize"

end
```

What should I do to fix this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From http://siawyoung.com/coding/ruby/invalid-gemspec.html

It turns out this happens because the gemspec gets the list of files from the command

```
`git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
```

So remove the file `popular_deals-0.1.0.gem` from the repository and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion but didn't work! :-(

Comment: @HimaChhag Did you push the file removal to the gem repository? I still can see it at https://github.com/HimaChitalia/popular-deals-from-slickdeals.net-cli

Comment: .. No, I didn't, I was just trying to find solution local first. Do I have too?

Comment: As `bundle install` goes to the gem repository to install it, I think so, unless you're specifying the local source path in the Gemfile.

Comment: You were right! After deleting .gem file, I pushed everything on github, I deleted local copy, cloned again, it started working!  But that gives me a question, don't we need this file in our repo for our gem to work? How will gem work without this file?

Comment: AFAIK this file is required only at rubygems, but not in the repo. You can confirm this looking for other famous gem repositories, like rails, rspec, etc. I think the gemspec file is the one required in your repo.

Answer (score 11):

```
rm popular_deals-0.1.0.gem
git add .
bundle install
```

Notice, you need **git add .** before **bundle install**, because you need update list of files.

Comment: You really saved me there - I had removed but wasn't running git add before bundle install. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the another answers not working with my need wich is to upload all my different versions to my repo.

Some minutes ago I was havinmg the same problem, try modifying your gemspec 'files' property to this:

```rb
spec.files = Dir.glob("{bin,lib}/**/*")
```

Let me know if it worked for you.